# Why does SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Resize returns null?

Tags: skia, skiasharp

The [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Resize/p/SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo/SkiaSharp.SKBitmapResizeMethod/) says:

> returns the resized bitmap if the resize operation could be
>   performed, otherwise null.

That **clearly** doesn't help. At all.
It could at least give us a enum / error code / whatever.

So I downloaded the lib's source and found out that `SKBitmaps.resize` ultimately calls `SKPixmap.Resize`, which in turns calls `SkiaApi.sk_bitmapscaler_resize`...

And that's the end of the road, because `SkiaApi.sk_bitmapscaler_resize` is implemented [(here)](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/binding/Binding/SkiaApi.cs) as `extern`.

So I proceeded to download the actual [Skia](https://github.com/google/skia) (since SkiaSharp is just a thin wrapper) to try and find out why sometimes this method fails.

But I just can't find out to which function / method `SkiaApi.sk_bitmapscaler_resize` is mapped to.

Can someone tell me to which function it's mapped?
Or even better, why does sometimes this method fails?

Answer (score 0):

The Google code is a bit vague, that is why the SkiaSharp docs are limited.

But... Looking at the code, it appears that both the source and the destination color type needs to be the 32-bit platform color types (Bgra8888 or Rgba888).

You can also check to make sure the pixel address (`GetPixels()`) is correct (not `null`/`IntPtr.Zero`).

Finally, make sure that the destination size is `>= 1`.